# Run a multi-line script in Screen

Tags: command-line, scripts, screen

I want to run this script in a screen:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    java -server -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar craftbukkit.jar
    echo "If you want to completely stop the server process now, press Ctrl+C before the time is up!"
    echo "Rebooting in:"
    for i in 5 4 3 2 1
    do
        echo "$i..."
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "Rebooting now!"
done
```

How do I do this?

(Script is for a Minecraft server. This is the source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zachoz/CrashPrevention/master/start.sh)

Comment: Did you try `screen /path/to/script`?

Comment: It returned something like "!/bin/bash not found", but I didn't have time to read it all.

Comment: What is the output of `type bash` on your system?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I created 2 scripts, the first runs the script in screen:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S server $HOME/rubix/start.sh
```

The next is what the first runs, which you can see above.